# Different Header Buttons for tabbed navigation react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

My question relates to how to set up tabbed navigator with the ability to call a function on the header to save each tab. I could put everything on one screen or add a button to the screen but I think a save button on the header would look nicer if possible.

My files are: [Screen1Component.js, Screen2Component.js, Navigator.js]

```
Settings: {
    screen: SettingsTabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerTitle: '',
        headerRight: () => (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                <Item 
                    title="Save" 
                    iconName="clipboard-check" 
                    onPress={//This needs to call a submitHandler function}
                />
            </HeaderButtons>
        )
    }
}
```

Now the above code works if its a stack navigator and I use it within the component file as below:

```
Screen1Component.navigationOptions = navData => {
const submitFn = navData.navigation.getParam('submit');
return {
    headerTitle: 'Create Settings here',
    headerRight: () => (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
            <Item 
                title="Save" 
                iconName="clipboard-check" 
                onPress={submitFn}
            />
        </HeaderButtons>
    )
}
```

}

But if I add both screens to a material bottom tabs navigator it disregards the navigationOptions in the screen files (which I need as I need each to call a separate submitfn). If I can just pass the code up to the navigator.js file that would work to but I have "writer's block" on how to word that in google search.

I am working with versions:
"expo": "~38.0.8",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
"react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.3.0"

Comment: Header buttons don't exist in the context of tabbed navigation, you define them on a stack navigator. But more importantly what do you mean when you say you want to save each tab?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using react-navigation v5?

Comment: Started learning through udemy and they used v4. This is my first app alone so wanted to finish one before moving to v5.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden - I meant each tab is its own screen in the tab navigator which each screen is its own component js file. I created my own header button from react-navigation-header-buttons. It works if I have it within the navigator file but I still would not know how to pass the submitfn to it from the component file.